# Get random strings from a list

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I have an ArrayList which is defined outside the main method, just inside the class StringRandomize:

```
 public static ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I also initialized a random object.

```
 Random obj = new Random();
```

Then I add some Strings to the list:

```
    StringRandomize.countries.add("USA");
    StringRandomize.countries.add("GB");
    StringRandomize.countries.add("Germany");
    StringRandomize.countries.add("Austria");
    StringRandomize.countries.add("Romania");
    StringRandomize.countries.add("Moldova");
    StringRandomize.countries.add("Ukraine");
```

How do I make those strings appear randomly? I need output like "Germany", "Moldova" and so on.
I need exactly the strings in the output, not their IDs.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `countries.get(index)`

Comment: "Cannot resolve symbol 'index' "
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to print the all content (and not just fetch a random element), you can also consider shuffling the list with `Collections.shuffle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use something like:

```
countries.get(Math.abs(new Random().nextInt()) % countries.size());
```

Or, to avoid creating a new `Random` object every time, you could use the same one:

```
Random gen = new Random();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(countries.get(Math.abs(gen.nextInt()) % countries.size()));
}
```

Comment: or `.nextInt(countries.size())`.

Comment: can we do like this  countries.get(obj.nextInt()); ?

Comment: @AlexisC: That's true. You can do that, also. @AmanKumar:  You can, but pay attention to avoid a potential indexOutOfBounds exception. You have to make sure that obj.nextInt() is positive and less than `countries.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void shuffleArray(string[] ar)
  {
    //set the seed for the random variable
    Random rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    //go from the last element to the first one.
    for (int i = ar.size()- 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      //get a random number till the current position and simply swap elements
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      // Simple swap
      int a = ar[index];
      ar[index] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = a;
    }
  }
```

This way you shuffle the entire array and get the values in a random order but NO duplicate at all. Every single element changes position, so that no matter what element (position) you pick, you get a country from a random position. You can return the entire vector, the positions are random.

Comment: Could you comment it please? And by the way, I get the " Cannot resolve method 'length()' " error.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Collections.shuffle(countries)` if you wanted a randomized List.

Else a `new Random().nextInt(max)` like Flavius described.